# Disable everything in view components while invoking

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, components

Below is My code in one of the view page (Details.Cshtml)

```
<div id="QAcomp" >
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("QuestionAnswers", new { activityQuestionAnswersList = Model.ActivityQuestionAnswers?.ToList() })
</div>
```

This above code invokes component question and answers based on the UI values.
My Question now is how to view the components in Details.cshtml page with only readonly or disabled. i mean what ever the content is , it should be disabled . and user should not be able change it.

Can any one help me on this ?

```
 public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(IList<ActivityQuestionAnswersModel> activityQuestionAnswersList = null, bool readsonly = false)
    {
        var questions = await _context.FQuestions.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(s=>s.DisplayOrder)

            .ProjectTo<QuestionsViewModel>().ToListAsync();
        ViewData["readonly"] = readsonly;


        return activityQuestionAnswersList == null
            ? View(questions)
            : View("ActivityQuestionAnswers",GetActivityQuesetions(questions, activityQuestionAnswersList));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ViewComponent, it will be rendered as Html in the web browser. So, if you want disable everything in the ViewComponent, you will need to control the Contoller styles in the ViewComponent.

Without adding `disabled` on every tags, I suggest you try `css` to format your view.

You could try to add content below to `wwwroot/css/site.css`:

```
#QAcomp {
text-decoration: none;
pointer-events: none;
}

#QAcomp input {
    display: block;
}
```

If there are some controls not disabled, you could add extra styles to disable them.

Update

gray out

```
#QAcomp {
text-decoration: none;
pointer-events: none;
```

}

```
#QAcomp input {
    display: block;
    background-color: #eee;
}
#QAcomp select {
    display: block;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: is there a special property in CSS to gray out only textboxes, dropdowns inside the div QAcomp ?

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter to `InvokeAsync`, which you're already utilizing, is the params that get passed to the `InvokeAsync` method on your view component. Just as you're already passing in your QA list, go ahead and pass a `bool` as well, indicating whether it's readonly or not.

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(
    List<ActivityQuestionAnswers> activityQuestionAnswersList, bool readonly = false)
{
    ViewData["readonly"] = readonly;
    ...
```

Then:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("QuestionAnswers", new { activityQuestionAnswersList = Model.ActivityQuestionAnswers?.ToList(), readonly = true })
```

Then, you can utilize this bool in your view to add the `readonly` attribute to your inputs:

```
@{
    var readonly = ViewData["readonly"] as bool? ?? false;
}

...

<input asp-for="Foo" readonly="@readonly">
```

If `@readonly` is `false` or `null`, Razor will omit the attribute.

Comment: i changed the below method to following. but did not work as narrated by you. still i see the dropdowns in component able to edit and i wanted them to gray out or disable

Comment: You likely want to set the `disabled` attribute then. It works the same.